# How do I write a conditional rewrite rule based on a cookie value?

Tags: apache, redirect, cookies

I need to redirect the user to a specific URL in case we have cookie with a certain value.

I am going with Apache redirect rules for this.

Here are the rules:

```
Cookie name : location

Values : "US" or "IN"
```

I have two requirements:

1. If cookie is present and has value "IN", then we have to redirect the user to "IN" site.

For example : if user hits URL : abc.stack.com or abc.stack.com/testarea/

It should change to the following URL : `abc.stack.com/IN` or `abc.stack.com/IN/testarea/`

2. If the cookie value is "US",  then it should redirect to the normal url:

For example: `abc.stack.com/IN/testarea/` to `abc.stack.com/testarea/`

I need to make sure I am not entering in a redirect loop.

My current Aapache redirect section looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} location=IN
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abc.stack.com/IN/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I was just trying to get at least requirement 1 working, but the url is not redirecting.

My access log looks like this:

```
"100.11.54.8" - - [23/Sep/2016:18:10:25 +0000] "GET /IN HTTP/1.1" 301 219 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
 like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.75 Safari/537.36" "location=IN; nlbi_435915=Em3sAG2OUBiQc4ffZp+CYAAAAABH5FXn3YIaf+KMpAKRSRHI; visid_incap_435
915=P8eS1zXURYmkaauIQdPpfLjHw1cAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAABmOjAjz+yhR5sOXnKJq53; incap_ses_218_435915=W/ncFPj80GPWZElELH8GA8Dz5FcAAAAAfUVaIUxikCbxh8hdcQ8A
7g==; _ga=GA1.2.914770215.1472448448; location=IN; _ga=GA1.3.914770215.1472448448; _dc_gtm_UA-59928833-1=1; visitor_id68942=11431130"
```

I am using POSTMAN to pass the cookie for testing.

Any help or guidance on the matter is much appreciated.